# Angle bisector Poincare plane

Tags: geometry

> How do I find the angle bisector, in the Poincare plane, of $\angle ABC$ if $A=(0,5), B=(0,3)$ and $C=(2,\sqrt{21})$?

Seems like a simple problem but I am having difficulty solving it. I found the angle of $\angle ABC$ to be $36.9$ degrees but I don't know how to find the angle bisector.

An angle bisector is defined as being a ray $BD$ of $\angle ABC$ with $D\in \angle ABC$ and $m(\angle ABD)=m(\angle DBC)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hyperbolic line $AB$ is the imaginary axis, with ideal endpoints $0$ and $\infty$. The hyperbolic line $BC$ is the Euclidean circle with center $(4,0)$ and radius $5$, so its endpoints are $(-1,0)$ and $(9, 0)$. A generic circle through $B$ will have center $(x,0)$ and radius $r=\sqrt{9+x^2}$ so it will have ideal points $(x-\sqrt{9+x^2},0)$ and $(x+\sqrt{9+x^2},0)$.

Now the endpoints of the angle bisector form a harmonic set with two of the endpoints of the original lines. I know this from the Cayley-Klein model of hyperbolic geometry, but since the models do agree along the boundary, it must be true for the Poincaré half plane as well. The choice of which endpoints you use will decide which bisector you get. Let's define

$$ a=0 \qquad b_1=-1 \qquad b_2=9 \qquad c=x-\sqrt{9+x^2} \qquad d=x+\sqrt{9+x^2} $$

From that you can compute

$$ -1=\operatorname{cr}(c,d;a,b_i) =\frac{(c-a)(d-b_i)}{(c-b_i)(d-a)} $$

and solving that for $x$ [using a suitable computer algebra system](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20%28%28x-sqrt%289%2bx%5E2%29%29*%28x%2bsqrt%289%2bx%5E2%29-b%29%29/%28%28x-sqrt%289%2bx%5E2%29-b%29*%28x%2bsqrt%289%2bx%5E2%29%29%29=-1) will give you

$$ x_i = -\frac{9}{b_i} $$

So you have two solutions for where the center may lie, $x_1=9$ and $x_2=-1$. Which are exactly the endpoints of your hyperbolic line $BC$. So take either of these enpoints and draw a circle around it through $B$, and you have one bisector. Do so for both endpoints and you get both bisectors. Using $\infty$ instead of $0$ in the above computation would eventually yield the same two circles, so there are no more than two angular bisectors. Determining the equations of these circles should be easy now.

[image: Illustration]

Now that we have this result, we can start looking for a simpler explanation. The key fact here is that one of the lines is vertical, i.e. passes through $\infty$. Now you can use another defining property of angle bisectors: reflection in an angle bisector will exchange the original lines. Hyperbolic reflection is Euclidean circle inversion, and circle inversion exchanges the center of the circle with the point at infinity. In our case, the center of the circle would be an ideal point of the non-vertical line, and the radius would be chosen in such a way that the circle passes through $B$. So reflection does indeed exchange two endpoints of two different lines. Since the circle passes through $B$, it will map that point onto itself. And since any two points in the hyperbolic plane have a unique line joining them, even if one or even both of these points are ideal, the two lines are indeed exchanged.